# PHP Preg replace to remove all xml

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am having a text area in my UI and I would like to filter out all xml(including html) text entered by user using preg_replace. I need a some help with it.

Eg:

```
Emailed user sam at 12:15 PM
<details><email>sam@sam.com</email></details>
```

After preg_replace :

```
Emailed user sam at 12:15 PM
```

Along with this any pointers to preg_replace regex would be great. I tried using some java regex(I am new to PHP) in preg_replace and found that it did not work. I am not sure if my regex was wrong or preg_replace uses different kind of regex.

All your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: @Raidenace it will strip any tag iirc. Mind showing example of tags it won't strip?

Comment: @ColeJohnson well, maybe it shall be rephrased, but it is my answer (OP said it's new to PHP so ). Use strip_tags().

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: I stand corrected. +1 for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )`

So something like the following will work in most cases,

```
$str_out = preg_replace('/<[\/]{0,1}\w[^>]*>/g', '', $str_in);
```

Where `'/<[\/]{0,1}\w[^>]*>/g'` is regex for <name stuff> and </name stuff>. It will fail if you've a > in an attribute (i.e. `<name blah=">hello">` will result in `hello">`

Although `strip_tags` is native so will be faster. Remember the arguments for `strip_tags` are the things to **not strip**

---

EDIT: If you want the content between the tags stripped out too, the regex for that is `'/<\w[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\w[^>]*>/g'`, but this will fail in even more situations (i.e. badly closed/nested tags), so you might want to run it first then the above on the result to make sure.

EDIT: Spelling

Comment: Also if it's to make sure people aren't submitting bad things, do this in a while loop until it stops making changes to make sure people don't do weird things expecting the removed bits of the string to create new tags, i.e. <<removeme></removeme>mytag>